# AngularJS ReferenceError: userRepository is not defined

Tags: angularjs

Here is my factory

```
   app = angular.module 'User', []
   app.factory 'userRepository', ->
  { getAllUsers: ->
    [
      {
        firstName: 'Name'
        lastName: 'lName'
        age: 29
      }
      {
        firstName: 'John'
        lastName: 'John'
        age: 32
      }
    ]
 }
```

Here is my controller

```
class UserModel
  @$inject: ['$scope',','userRepository']
  constructor: (@scope, @http) 
  .
  .
  console.log(userRepository)
  show: -> 
   console.log(userRepository)

app = angular.module 'UserReview', ["Questions"]
app.controller 'UserReviewCtrl', UserModel
```

Object get printed in constructor but in show method I get exception

> ReferenceError: userRepository is not defined

Comment: what is the syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
@$inject: ['$scope',','userRepository']
```

to

```
@$inject: ['$scope','userRepository']
```